# Build Android-openssl library for platform 2.1

Tags: android, java-native-interface, openssl, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I am using open-ssl source given at https://github.com/eighthave/openssl-android
to build a library which can be used in android project.

As per instructions given at README.txt,  I am able to compile it for the the Android platform version 2.2 (level -8)

But my app requires it to be 2.1 (level -7) compatible.

I tried following options with the default.properties file ( https://github.com/eighthave/openssl-android/blob/master/default.properties )

1) set target=android-7

2) set target=android-5

But when I compile it using command ndk-build, it gives following error

```
    Compile thumb  : crypto <= dsa_vrf.c
    Compile thumb  : crypto <= dso_dl.c
    Compile thumb  : crypto <= dso_dlfcn.c
    /Crypto/openssl-android/crypto/dso/dso_dlfcn.c: In function 'dlfcn_pathbyaddr':
    /Crypto/openssl-android/crypto/dso/dso_dlfcn.c:445: error: 'Dl_info' undeclared (first    use in this function)
    /Crypto/openssl-android/crypto/dso/dso_dlfcn.c:445: error: (Each undeclared identifier   is reported only once
    /Crypto/openssl-android/crypto/dso/dso_dlfcn.c:445: error: for each function it appears in.)
    /Crypto/openssl-android/crypto/dso/dso_dlfcn.c:445: error: expected ';' before 'dli'
    /Crypto/openssl-android/crypto/dso/dso_dlfcn.c:455: error: 'dli' undeclared (first use in this function)
    make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/crypto/dso/dso_dlfcn.o] Error 1
```

As per error message- Dl_info is not defined. but if we go to file dso_dlfcn.c , the definition for the structure is already provided. (https://github.com/eighthave/openssl-android/blob/master/crypto/dso/dso_dlfcn.c)

And this code compiled for target=android-8 in default properties file, but not for android-7 or android-5.

Request you to help me to resolve this error. and let me know what all changes needs to be done in order to compile it for android 2.1 platform.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You also have [OpenSSL and Android](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to include the following piece of code into dso_dlfcn.c:

```
typedef struct {
const char *dli_fname;  /* Pathname of shared object that
                           contains address */
void       *dli_fbase;  /* Address at which shared object
                           is loaded */
const char *dli_sname;  /* Name of nearest symbol with address
                           lower than addr */
void       *dli_saddr;  /* Exact address of symbol named
                           in dli_sname */
} Dl_info;
int dladdr(const void *addr, Dl_info *info) { return 0; }
```

Before:

```
#ifdef __linux
# ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#  define _GNU_SOURCE   /* make sure dladdr is declared */
# endif
#endif
```

After that in my case the library is built.

Comment: Thanks , library builds successfully.

Comment: This issue still exists..!! But the workaround suggested by @Yuri saved me.. Thanks :)

Comment: Not at all! Good luck with the experiments :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install with latest NDK version and update Application.mk file appropriately.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
APP_PLATFORM := android-19
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS += -frtti 
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
APP_CPPFLAGS += -DANDROID
APP_PROJECT_PATH := $(shell pwd)
APP_BUILD_SCRIPT := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../Android.mk
```

The above 2 problems will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had one issue with @Yuri's solution and had to improve it alittle. My `APP_ABI` is set to `all` in `Application.mk`. In my case it meant that among `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a` I'm building also for `x86` and `mips`. I have also `android-9` target installed in android sdk to use in other projects. `x86` and `mips` are supported by ndk starting from `android-9`. As written in the docs, when `ndk-build` will start building these targets, it will switch to `android-9` target automatically. And what? - Yes, it will fail to compile :-). Here is my solution:

1. In crypto/Android.mk find the line `local_c_flags :=
   -DNO_WINDOWS_BRAINDEATH`. After the line write this http://pastebin.com/7euUVD7A.
2. Yuri's code has to be inserted into `if defined`: http://pastebin.com/V58gTSBU
3. By the way, I've inserted Yuri's block after `#include <openssl/dso.h>` but not before `#ifdef __linux`